# How to compare data using Reflection between struct and map[string]interface{} in Golang

Tags: go, struct, reflection, compare

I am trying to compare these two interfaces together as a function. It is working as far as I am concerned. I am sending a struct in A interface{} and map[string]interface{} in B, having the same values but when being compared with reflect they are not resulting to be the same. I would like to be able to convert the map[string]interface{} into a struct interface inside this function so that my tests can get shorter. I have tried using https://github.com/mitchellh/copystructure, but does not work inside this function.(from outside it works though:

```
var m map[string]interface{}
var something StructType
err := mapstructure.Decode(m, &something)
```

if err....
and then i send the something in the B interface)

below is the function to compare the interfaces. You can copy and paste and see how it works for yourself

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Something struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Male bool
    Cars []string
}

func main() {
    var s Something
    s.Name = "joe"
    s.Male = true
    s.Age = 20
    s.Cars = []string{"Fordd", "Chevy", "Mazda"}
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["Name"] = "joe"
    m["Male"] = true
    m["Age"] = 20
    m["Cars"] = []string{"Fordd", "Chevy", "Mazda"}
    //with map[string]interface{} although the same values it does not work
    log.Println("Are these the same: ", CompareData(s, m))
    //with struct of same type it works
    var s2 Something
    s2.Name = "joe"
    s2.Male = true
    s2.Age = 20
    s2.Cars = []string{"Fordd", "Chevy", "Mazda"}
    log.Println("Are these the same: ", CompareData(s, s2))

    }

func CompareData(A interface{}, B interface{}) bool {
    a := reflect.ValueOf(A)
    b := reflect.ValueOf(B)
    akind := a.Kind().String()
    bkind := a.Kind().String()
    if akind == "slice" && bkind == "slice" {
        for i := 0; i < a.Len(); i++ {
            // log.Println("they are sliced")
            CompareData(a.Index(i).Interface(), b.Index(i).Interface())
            // log.Println("\n", a.Index(i).Interface(), "\n", b.Index(i).Interface())
        }
        // t.Fatal("this is a slice you need to iterate over the values")
    } else {
        // log.Println("\n\n", A, "\n", B)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(a.Interface(), b.Interface()) {
            log.Println("These should be equal\nSuccessData:\t", a.Interface(), "\nData:\t\t", b.Interface())
            return false
        }
        // log.Println("\nA:\t", A, "\nB:\t", B)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: "does not work inside this function" in what way? What problem are you having?

Comment: I was trying to convert the map[string]interface{} into a struct but am not experienced enough with reflection so, I could not initialise an object of type A and decode the values from object B into the newly initialised object.

Comment: "Cloud not" why? What problem specifically are you having - i.e. what is the behavior you're getting and how is it different from the desired behavior?